# Are weak-star limits in $L^\infty (0,T;L^2(\Omega))$ and in $L^\infty (\Omega \times \left[ 0,T \right])$ equal?

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence, pointwise-convergence, bochner-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $T>0$.

Let $u_n$ be a sequence such that there exists a subsequence (still denoted by $u_n$)
\begin{equation} u_n \rightarrow u \text{ weakly-star in } L^\infty (0,T;L^2(\Omega))
\end{equation}
and that there exists a subsequence (again denoted by $u_n$) such that

\begin{equation} u_n \rightarrow u^*\text{ weakly-star in } L^\infty (\Omega \times \left[ 0,T \right]) \end{equation}

Is it possible to imply from this that the limits are equal, i.e. $u = u^*$?

I need this property for a proof, but I have no approach how to show it, the only thing I know is that $L^\infty( 0,T; L^\infty (\Omega)) \subset L^\infty (\Omega \times \left[ 0,T \right])$, see question [$L^\infty((0,T)\times\Omega)$ is not equal to $L^\infty(0,T;L^\infty(\Omega))$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716809/l-infty0-t-times-omega-is-not-equal-to-l-infty0-tl-infty-omega).

Answer (score 1):

Let $I=(0,T)$.
The space $L^\infty(I,L^2(\Omega))$ is the dual of $L^1(I,L^2(\Omega))$, while $L^\infty(\Omega \times I)$ is the dual of $L^1(\Omega\times I)$.
Hence, the weak-star convergence is tested against functions in $L^1(I,L^2(\Omega))$ and $L^1(\Omega\times I)=L^1(I,L^1(\Omega))$.
Now, $L^1(I,L^1(\Omega)) \supset L^1(I,L^2(\Omega))$, so weak-star convergence in $L^\infty(\Omega \times I)$ implies weak-star convergence in $L^\infty(I,L^2(\Omega))$, and the limits are equal.

Comment: Thank you. Does this mean $u = u^* \in L^\infty(I,L^2(\Omega))$ or $u = u^* \in L^\infty (\Omega \times I)$?

Comment: This means $u=u* \in L^\infty(I,L^2) \cap L^\infty(\Omega \times I)$.